# Horário de verão errado

Tags: php, apache

Estou com um problema em relação ao horário de verão... na verdade celulares, relógios de rua, meu pc também adiantou o relógio...

> Em geral, o horário de verão começa em outubro. Mas, para não coincidir com a data das eleições, o presidente Michel Temer assinou um decreto no fim de 2017 adiando o período para novembro.

Já reparei que alguns sites estão com o horário de verão. Pelo que andei lendo, é o apache quem tem o papel de gerir quando inicia e termina o horário de verão.

A questão é - o nosso horário foi adiado e ninguém falou pro apache (rs). Qual seria a maneira de atualizar o apache para as datas corretas, **sem** ter que fazer gambiarras no PHP do tipo `(hora - 1)`?

Comment: Curioso, não cheguei a instalar ainda a atualização KB, mas a hora está correta mas indicando que está no fuso horário: **Mon, 22 Oct 2018 06:10:41 -0200**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Se o problema for no OS

Em Linux você precisa fazer um update, que provavelmente trará o TZDATA correto (o Apache pega do OS). Se for corrigir manualmente, tem que ver onde sua distro armazena os dados de horário de verão (não confundir com os fusos horários, e nem com NTP).

Se for windows, tem um KB específico para horário de verão deste ano nos updates, caso seu OS não tenha atualizado automaticamente (o que parece ser o caso). - No caso do Windows, segue o link para 2019:

> http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/search.aspx?q=4501226

### Se o problema for no PHP

O PHP tem o "timezonedb", que faz o papel de "tabela" de horários de verão por ano e região geográfica. Neste caso, atualize por este pacote: http://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb

Eventualmente pode ser que você precise reiniciar algum serviço (O servidor de páginas, ou o serviço do PHP se este foi instalado como algum tipo de CGI)

Comment: Estou tentando instalar essa extensão no wamp 3.1.0. O wamp até reconhece a .dll na pasta mas diz que não consta no php.ini. Tem algum segredo para instalar ela no wamp?

Comment: Deveria funcionar só trocando a original, sem precisar nada adicional. Você tentou instalar manualmente ou usou o PECL?

Comment: Manualmente. Conaegui afinal. Na vdd precisava ser a versão 2018.7 eu estava instalando a 2018.3..

Comment: @Matheus ainda bem que resolveu.. se bem que amanhã já perde o sentido né, pq o horário muda :D

Comment: Pois é, até ia conentar isso, agora o problema se resolveu sozinho. Me pergunto se essa atualização corrigiu somente o ano de 2018 ou se botaram como padrao, de 2018 em diante, a data de início do horário de verão como 4 de novembro... Será q ano q tem outro patch desses? xD

Comment: @Matheus cada ano é uma entrada na tabela de timezone, então tem que ficar esperto com os patches. Tem país que muda fixo o horário de verão, sempre na mesma data, aí sempre funciona. O Brasil é ano a ano mesmo, varia. Eleições geralmente interferem no processo, adiando a virada para não mexer com horário da votação

Comment: Não sabia que o brasil era variável, nunca tinha me atentado. Mas ficarei esperto para os próximos anos. Felizmente tem os patches da PECL :)

Answer (score 2):

Windows:

- Publicar a DLL php_timezonedb.dll no diretório de extensões do PHP. Ex.: “c:\php\ext”

Link para download da DLL: https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb

- Acrescentar o parâmetro “extension=php_timezonedb.dll” no arquivo php.ini
- Reiniciar o serviço do APACHE

Linux:

- Baixar o arquivo timezonedb.tgz do site https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb
- utilizar o comando #pecl upgrade timezonedb.tgz

OBS.: Pode ser que falhas de dependências que precisaram ser resolvidas antes que o comando seja executado com sucesso.

- acrescentar a linha “extension=timezonedb.so” no arquivo php.ini
- Reiniciar o serviço httpd

Answer (score 1):

**Se o problema for no PHP (minha versão é a 5.5):**

**Instale o php55-devel usando o comando:**

```
sudo yum install php55-devel
```

**depois instale o timezonedb usando o comando:**

```
sudo pecl install timezonedb
```

**depois abra o seu arquivo php.ini, na pasta onde ele estiver:**

```
sudo nano /etc/php.ini
```

**e acrescente a seguinte linha e salve o arquivo:**

```
extension=timezonedb.so
```

**depois reinicie o apache com o comando:**

```
sudo service httpd restart
```