# Sevidor com horário correto, mas PHP com hora adiantada

Tags: php, time

Meu servidor (Cent OS) está com o horário correto (10:10 horário que estou criando a postagem), mas no PHP quando eu dou o comando `echo date('H:i')` o resultado é 11:10 (uma hora adiantado). Não sei o que pode estar causando esse problema.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/337935/hor%C3%A1rio-de-ver%C3%A3o

Comment: valew, só atualizar o timezonedb do php