# Calcular diferença entre datas (sem horas) com strtotime - uso de date_default_timezone_set() dá resultados diferentes

Tags: php, data, timezone

#### Cenário exemplo

Tive um problema com uma simples contagem de dias entre 2 datas.

Uma me resultava em 5 e a outra 6, sendo que estava utilizando as mesmas datas com a mesma função, apenas em arquivos diferentes.

A função:

```
$dt_inicial = "2019-11-01"
$dt_final   = "2019-11-07"
$dias       = (int) floor((strtotime($dt_final) - strtotime($dt_inicial))/(60*60*24));
```

*E ainda, se não estou ficando louco, o horário atual no momento de execução influencia o resultado.*

As datas foram: `2019-11-01` e `2019-11-07`.

Então, olhando o que tinha de errado, percebi que (tirando o fato de ter as mesma função em 2 lugares diferentes) o que estava dando o problema, era em um dos arquivos estar setado `date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo')` e no outro não, assim, assumindo o padrão.

---

#### Dúvidas

- Deveria eu adicionar as "horas" (00:00:00 e 23:59:59) nas datas para evitar o problema?
- Quando utilizo o `strtotime` com uma data, sem horas, ele pega a hora atual?
- Qual a correta utilização do `date_default_timezone_set()` nesses casos?
- Usar essa fórmula para cálculo de diferença de dias está correto?
- Existem formas mais exatas de calcular diferença entre datas?

Comment: Quais os valores de `$dt_final` e `$dt_inicial`? Se um estiver antes e o outro depois de uma transição de horário de verão, pode dar resultados estranhos mesmo. Qual o timezone padrão que estava no outro arquivo? Quando a string só tem a data sem as horas, `strtotime`, se não me engano, usa meia-noite no timezone default que estiver setado no momento.

Comment: Rapaz, tem gente muito infeliz nesse SOpt. Os caras -1 porque só assim acham que atingem alguém, justificando a incapacidade de entender a pergunta. Kkkkkk

Comment: Só pra deixar claro que não fui eu que negativei - inclusive, eu quero responder a pergunta, mas preciso dos detalhes que pedi no comentário anterior... :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo eu sei que não foi você, sabemos os tipos de pessoas que fazem isso! rs
Eu não coloquei data específica porque como eu disse abaixo do exemplo, acredito que o horário influencia, então a pessoa tentaria simular e não chegaria no resultado dependendo como for. As datas foram: `2019-11-01` e `2019-11-07`. Em um arquivo não tinha o `date_default_timezone_set()` e no outro, tinha `date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo')`. O teste que fiz ontem foi por volta das 16:50h.

Comment: @hkotsubo Só complementando, em teste que fiz, sim, o `strtotime` completa com 00:00:00 as datas sem horas. Por isso até coloquei em questão fixar as horas nas datas, se isso mudaria algo, evitaria problemas, etc.

Comment: Bom, em 2019 o horário de verão foi cancelado (a transição seria em 3 de novembro, se não me engano). Então se o PHP não foi atualizado, ele ainda acha que existiu essa transição e pode dar essa diferença mesmo. Vou fazer uns testes aqui e respondo assim que possível

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diferença entre datas é mais complicado do que parece. No seu caso, parece ser um problema relacionado ao horário de verão.

No timezone `America/Sao_Paulo`, em 2019, o horário de verão *teria* início em 3 de novembro, mas [foi cancelado](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_ato2019-2022/2019/decreto/D9772.htm). Só que muitos sistemas não foram atualizados e ainda "acreditam" que o horário de verão existiu neste período ([veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/337935/112052) como atualizar o PHP nesses casos).

"Por sorte" o PHP que tenho instalado aqui também não foi atualizado, então consegui fazer um teste similar ao seu.

---

#### `strtotime`

Vamos ver como a [função `strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) se comporta com as datas que você indicou:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
echo strtotime('2019-11-01'); // 1572577200
echo strtotime('2019-11-07'); // 1573092000
```

Quando o horário não é fornecido, ela assume "meia-noite no timezone default". Eu setei o timezone para `America/Sao_Paulo` ([que é o equivalente ao Horário Oficial de Brasília](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/259120/112052)), então ela considera meia-noite neste timezone. Só lembrando que `strtotime` retorna o valor do timestamp (veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/431058/112052) o que é esse valor).

No primeiro caso, o timestamp é 1572577200, que corresponde a 1 de novembro de 2019, à meia-noite, Horário de Brasília. Neste instante ainda não estava em horário de verão, então este timestamp equivale a `2019-11-01T03:00Z` (1 de novembro de 2019, às 3 da manhã, [**em UTC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)) - já que, quando não está em horário de verão, o Horário de Brasília está 3 horas atrás do UTC.

No segundo caso, o timestamp é 1573092000, que corresponde a 7 de novembro de 2019, à meia-noite, Horário de Brasília. Mas lembre-se que meu PHP não foi atualizado e ainda acha que no dia 03/11/2019 começou o horário de verão. E o que acontece nesse dia? À meia-noite, o relógio é adiantado em uma hora, então todos os minutos entre 00:00 e 00:59 são pulados (na prática, esse dia teve apenas 23 horas de duração, justamente porque uma hora foi "pulada"). Por isso esse timestamp corresponde a `2019-11-07T02:00Z` (7 de novembro, às 2 da manhã, em UTC - e não mais 3 da manhã, como no primeiro caso - pois quando é horário de verão, o Horário de Brasília passa a ficar 2 horas atrás do UTC, justamente por adiantar o relógio em uma hora).

Por isso a diferença entre as duas datas é de 514800 segundos, o que equivale a 143 horas, ou ainda 5.958333333 dias. E arredondando para baixo (já que você usou [`floor`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php)), dá 5 dias.

Para que o resultado fosse 6 dias, seria necessário ter uma diferença de 144 horas, mas graças à transição do horário de verão, uma hora foi pulada e é daí que vem essa diferença de 1 hora a menos. Por isso o cálculo falha, já que `60 * 60 * 24` considera que todos os dias tem sempre 24 horas.

Se eu mudar o timezone default para algum que não possui transição de horário de verão no intervalo entre as datas (por exemplo, `America/Los_Angeles`), a diferença passa a ser de 144 horas e o cálculo retorna corretamente 6 dias. Provavelmente é por isso que um dos scripts funciona e o outro não, pois o que não tem a chamada para [`date_default_timezone_set`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set) está usando o *default* que está configurado no PHP, que deve ser diferente de `America/Sao_Paulo` (você pode verificar qual é usando [`date_default_timezone_get`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php)).

---

Se quer levar em conta somente a diferença em dias, ignorando o horário, uma maneira é considerar que as datas estão em UTC (já que o UTC não sofre efeitos de horário de verão). Além disso, você pode usar um [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php), passando como parâmetro um [`DateTimeZone`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) correspondente a UTC:

```
$utc = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$inicio = new DateTime('2019-11-01', $utc);
$fim = new DateTime('2019-11-07', $utc);

$diferenca = $inicio->diff($fim);

echo "A diferença é de {$diferenca->days} dias"; // A diferença é de 6 dias
```

O método [`diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) retorna um [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php), que terá a quantidade total de dias em [`days`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php#dateinterval.props.days).

Dessa forma você não precisa usar [`date_default_timezone_set`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set), pois ele altera o timezone default para todo o script (e nem sempre é isso que você quer). Usando um `DateTimeZone` específico somente onde preciso, tenho mais controle sobre onde e quando estou usando aquele timezone, sem afetar as demais partes do script.

---

Obviamente que quando não há transição de horário de verão entre as datas inicial e final, ambas as soluções (`strtotime` e `DateTime`) funcionam.

> *Existem formas mais exatas de calcular diferença entre datas?*

A forma "correta" de calcular diferença entre duas datas depende muito de cada caso. [Aritmética de datas](https://hkotsubo.github.io/tag/aritm%C3%A9tica) é bem [confusa e muitas vezes contra-intuitiva](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/01/the-joys-of-date-time-arithmetic/), e dependendo do critério que você usa, os resultados podem ser completamente diferentes.

Pode ser que você só queira a [diferença em meses, desconsiderando o dia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/370215/112052), pode ser que queira a diferença exata em dias, horas, minutos, segundos, etc. Cada forma vai exigir um cálculo diferente (ex: se uma pessoa nasceu em 29/02/2000, em 28/02/2001 ela já completou 1 ano? Cada API/linguagem pode retornar um resultado diferente ao calcular a quantidade de anos entre essas datas - algumas podem dar zero, outras podem dar 1).

Enfim, há *corner cases* demais e não há uma única forma "correta" de calcular diferença entre datas. Cada caso é um caso.

Comment: Você me lembrou de um detalhe... o retorno é 5 e 6, porque eu adiciono +1 para considerar outro dia cheio. Como o `strtotime` preenche com `00:00:00`, quando se tira a diferença "se perde" os 2 dias data. Vou acertar na pergunta.

Comment: Então, mas porque será que me deu a diferença por volta das 17h? Não consigo entender... se fosse na virada do dia, aí faria sentido... ou estou deixando passar algo!?

Comment: @rbz Não sei, ele usou a hora atual ou algum valor diferente dos que vc passou? Tem algum outro detalhe no cálculo que não foi mostrado? Se vc rodar com o código que passei, com `DateTime`, ocorre o mesmo problema? Veja também o valor do timezone default no script que não muda para America/Sao_Paulo (rode `date_default_timezone_get()` nele e veja qual é)

Comment: Vou esperar as 16h para fazer o teste! rs

Comment: @rbz Estranho, o horário que roda não deveria influenciar, pois vc usa somente a data e por isso ele sempre seta o horário pra meia-noite. Pode ser que alguém tenha arrumado a config do PHP, rode `echo (new DateTime('2019-11-07', new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo')))->format(DateTime::ATOM);` e veja o resultado. Se no final estiver `-02:00`, o PHP ainda acha que tem horário de verão, se estiver `-03:00` a config foi corrigida.

Comment: Então... as datas são fixas... ele vai dar 00:00:00 para tudo... não deveria ser fixa de qq jeito?

Comment: @rbz Se as datas são fixas, então é o que já respondi (dependendo do timezone pode dar 5 ou 6). E não deveria depender do horário que roda... Meu chute é que pode ter algum outro lugar mudando o timezone, sei lá - eu colocaria um `echo date_default_timezone_get()` só pra ver o que cada script está usando, pra ter certeza...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104760/discussion-between-rbz-and-hkotsubo).